# How to synchronize IO with OpenMP section

Tags: io, synchronization, openmp

when I execute the code below the shell output might overlap between thread 0 and thread 1. 
So I would like to ask you what is the best way to make sure that each thread finishes output writing before the other one starts output?

This would make sure that the ouput is clean.

Many thanks in advance!

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(emperor)
    {
#pragma omp sections
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
                cout << "Open the listening thread by using openmp!"  << endl;
                emperor->startServerListening(); /// does some work
            }
#pragma omp section
            {
                cout << "Open the master thread by using openmp!" << endl;
                emperor->startServerCoupling(); /// does some other work
            }
        } /// End of sections
    } /// End of parallel section
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use a critical section, so that only one thread at a time writes to output:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(emperor)
{
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            #pragma omp critical (cout)
                cout << "Open the listening thread by using openmp!"  << endl;
            emperor->startServerListening(); /// does some work
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            #pragma omp critical (cout)
                cout << "Open the master thread by using openmp!" << endl;
            emperor->startServerCoupling(); /// does some other work
        }
    } /// End of sections
} /// End of parallel section
```

You may use named critical sections to identify exclusive sections, i.e. named sections are exclusive to all sections with the same name (one thread in one section at a time). Unnamed sections are exclusive to all other unnamed sections.